# Identify the layers of a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Do i get this comments right? Are those the 5 layers of my model, as described below?

## Model

```
    # input - conv - conv - linear - linear(fc)
    def model(data): # input Layer

        # 1 conv Layer
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(data, layer1_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer1_biases) # Activation function

        # 1 conv Layer
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(hidden, layer2_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(conv + layer2_biases) # Activation function

        # not a layer ( just reshape)
        shape = hidden.get_shape().as_list()
        reshape = tf.reshape(hidden, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])

        # 1 linear layer - not fc due to relu
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)

        # 1 linear fully connected layer
        return tf.matmul(hidden, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    # 1 linear layer - not fc due to relu
    hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)
```

In this layer it is a fully connected layer and it is passed through a "RELU" Activation function. The layer of this code is this part

```
tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases
```

and you are sending this layer through a relu activation function

```
tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)
```

Other then this everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment labels are right but I think there is an issue with your code.

If you look at the definition of [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d):

```
conv2d(
    input,
    filter,
    strides,
    padding,
    use_cudnn_on_gpu=True,
    data_format='NHWC',
    name=None
)
```

You see that the second argument is not weights but the filter (kernel) shape, defined as: `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`

You could use [tf.layers.conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d) instead. It simplifies the code and does the weights, biases and activation in one line. e.g.

```
conv1 = conv2d(data, filters, kernel_size=[2, 2], padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
```